# How do I turn off function tooltips in chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, configuration, console, tooltip

I would prefer to keep it, but it always ends up hiding the information I was looking for

You can't even use ESC to get rid of it, you have to type something and delete it

[image: Very annoying]